# Register more than one user with Fortify

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-fortify

I'm new with laravel fortify and I'm trying to create more than one account for my project, but whenever I register the first account and try to access again the register page, it keeps redirecting me to home page. Please let me know if I need to post any more code here.

Here's my FortifyServiceprovider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use App\Responses\RegisterResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\RegisterResponse as RegisterResponseContract;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(
            RegisterResponseContract::class,
            RegisterResponse::class
        );
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        Fortify::loginView(function(){
            return view('index');
        });

        Fortify::registerView(function(){
            return view('register');
        });

        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->email.$request->ip());
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });
    }
    

}
```

Comment: logout ... you are currently authenticated as the user you registered, and registered users have no reason to be able to access the registration page, as they are already registered

Comment: @lagbox Thank you. Do you have any idea how can I do the logout or prevent it from login after registering? I can't find any info for fortify

Comment: the registration system is supposed to be so that users can register, not so someone else can enter new users into the system ... do you not plan on having users register themselves?

Comment: isn't there something in the upper right that drops down with a 'logout' link?

Comment: @lagbox If you're not using a [starter kit](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/starter-kits) and implementing Fortify yourself, you need to build all the views and create forms for things like logout.

Comment: @lagbox I've managed to find out how I can do the logout after registering, because I'm building the project without the starter kit as Unflux mentioned. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

for redirect after register

app -> Providers  -> RouteServiceProvider

```
public const HOME = '/home';
```

to

```
public const HOME = '/';
```